# Accessing a variable from another file in PHP, SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$paseoLocationTo=$_POST['locationTo'];
$paseoLocationFrom=$_POST['locationFrom'];
$PTime=$_POST['time'];

echo"The value of Location to is $paseoLocationTo </br>";
echo"The value of Location from is $paseoLocationFrom </br>";
echo"The value of time is $PTime </br>";

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
            or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('shuttle_service_system') 
    or die(mysql_error());

$TripID =mysql_query("
    SELECT DISTINCT Trip_ID as 'TripID'
    FROM trip
    WHERE Timeslot LIKE '$PTime' AND Location_From Like '$paseoLocationFrom' AND Location_To    LIKE '$paseoLocationTo'     
");
    echo "<form action='LastPage.php' method='post'>";
    while($check = mysql_fetch_array($TripID))
    **echo "<name='TripID' id='TripID'>" . $check['TripID'] . " ";**
    echo "<p class='sure'> Are you sure with your reservation? </p>";
    echo"<input type='submit' value='Submit' class='Log'>";
    echo"</form";
?>
```

From another php file, this the LastPage.php

```
<?php
**$TripID=$_POST['TripID'];
echo"The value of trip ID is $TripID </br>";**
?>
```

Hi guys I was wondering why I can't access the "TripID" variable in the other php file? I was accessing it before but now there seems to be a problem, am I doing it right? I'm sorry a php and SQL newbie.

Comment: This is by far the most invalid HTML and worst PHP I've ever seen. [encourage developers to keep their code readable, valid and cross-browser compatible](http://www.phtml.org)

Comment: Its a great think if this works without showing any error.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following lines

```
**echo "<name='TripID' id='TripID'>" . $check['TripID'] . " ";**
```

with

```
echo "<input type="hidden" name="TripID" value="'.$check['TripID'].'"  />";
```

So it will not be visible to user on current page but when you will post the Form, it will be available in $_POST['TripID'] variable.

One more thing your  tag is not properly closed.

Use MySQLi and prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

PS: accept the answer if its work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
 <input type="text" name="TripID" value="'.$check['TripID'].'" ... />
```

in your form in order to retrieve values with `$_POST['TripID']`.

There is no such thing as

```
 **echo "<name='TripID' id='TripID'>" . $check['TripID'] . " ";**
```

which was found in your code.

Comment: For sure, I didn't correct all the mistakes, just the one pointed out in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
**echo "<name='TripID' id='TripID'>" . $check['TripID'] . " ";**
```

Looks like that should be:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='TripID' id='TripID' value='" . $check['TripID'] . "' />";
```

If you don't want it to be editable, display it then add a hidden field:

```
echo $check['TripID'];
echo "<input type='hidden' name='TripID' id='TripID' value='" . $check['TripID'] . "' />";
```

Basically, you're not putting your trip id into an actual form tag, so it's not getting posted over to your LastPage.php.

Edit: fixed the first input to wrap the tripID in the value attribute.

Comment: Vinoth beat me to it. :)

Comment: I have always used `value="myValue"` to set up a default value to an input. Does `<input type="text">myValue</input>` as you suggested produce the same effects and is correct?

Comment: @destroydaworld no it's invalid HTML, `input` is a void element http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.text.html#input.text

Comment: Yeah, I had the input fixed in the second block, but missed it in the first block. correct syntax is <input value="" />. Going to update it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag is not closed properly. It is now as `echo </form";`

It should be    `echo"</form>";`

Also you didnt added name in input tag.

It should be

```
echo"<input type='submit' value="$check['TripID']" name="TripID" class='Log'>";
```

There is no name tag `<name>` but you used how?

Comment: `echo"` blankspace missing `echo "`; `"$check['TripID']"` dots missing `" . $check['TripID'] . "` You have errors in the answer omg don't advice people with wrong syntax

Comment: Thank you vinoth for spotting the missing ">" in form. :)